# Self referencing list in C#

Tags: c#, sql, key, self-reference

I'm working with BugReports in C#.
BugReports can have duplicates, so they have a self referencing DuplicateOf field. ( A list of BugReports)

```
public class BugReportDB
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ....
    //public int DuplicateId { get; set; }
    public virtual BugReportDB DuplicatedOf { get; set; }
}
```

Here's foreign key definition:

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<BugReportDB>().HasOptional(u => u.DuplicatedOf).WithMany().Map(fkamc => fkamc.MapKey("DuplicatedOf"));
```

For checking out if there are any duplicates I run the following method:

```
    var br = (from b in db.BugReport
                where b.Id == originalId
                select b);
            if (!br.Any())
                throw new NonexistentObjectException();
                foreach (var brep in br) { 
                if(brep.DuplicatedOf.Id==bugReportId)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

In my case instead of having a single BugReport for a single Id, I have many BugReports, one for every duplicate they have. For Example: BugReport A has 2 duplicates: B and C. In this case I'll have in DB a BugReport A with duplicate B and a BugReport with duplicate C.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance